# How to pass multiple filter parameters

Tags: laravel-4, before-filter

How can you pass multiple parameters to a filter?

This function in the compiled.php indicated that you use a comma as a separator

```
protected static function parseParameterFilter($filter)
{
    list($name, $parameters) = explode(':', $filter, 2);
    return array($name, explode(',', $parameters));
}
```

However, I try to dump the $value and only the first parameter is dumped. Why is this?